# How can I use together jquery,ajax and mysql?

Tags: c#, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have some codes.I want to add jquery and ajaxin my code.I tried but i didnt do it.

Here my jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnGOlustur_Click').click(function () {
        var Pro_id = $('#drop_p').val(); //drop_p is combobox' name.
        var Ity_id = $('#drop_i').val();
        var Sta_id = $('#drop_s').val();
        document.write("basliyorrrr");

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: 'GorevEkle.aspx/btnGOlustur_Click',
            data: "{'project_id':'" + Pro_id + "','status_id':'" + Sta_id + "','itype_id':'" + Ity_id + "'}",
            async: false,
            success: function (response) {
                $('#drop_p').val(''); $('#drop_i').val(''); $('#drop_s').val('');
                alert("Record saved successfully in database");
                document.write("dataabase e kaydedildi");
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("some problem in saving data");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

My save cs file

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod]
protected void btnGOlustur_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(Globals.CONNECTION_STRING);
        con.Open();
        String UserId = Session["user_id"].ToString();
        int Pro_id = Convert.ToInt32(drop_p.SelectedValue);
        int Sta_id = Convert.ToInt32(drop_s.SelectedValue);
        int Ity_id = Convert.ToInt32(drop_i.SelectedValue);
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO issue (user_id, project_id, status_id, itype_id) values ('" + UserId + "','" + Pro_id + "','" + Sta_id + "','" + Ity_id + "')", con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        lbl_hata.Text = "Error reading list of names. ";
        lbl_hata.Text += err.Message;
    }
    Response.Redirect("Profil.aspx");
}
```

here my error:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   An exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of mistakes in your code

1. [WebMethod] should be static to invoke it.
2. Move your btnGOlustur_Click logic to a separate static method
3. You can't make Response.Redirect in ajax context
4. Hook the value from Request.Params

Considering all the above

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod]
public static string MyMethod()
{
    try
    {
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(Globals.CONNECTION_STRING);
        con.Open();
        String UserId = HttpContext.Current.Session["user_id"].ToString();
        int Pro_id = HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["project_id"];
        //other values
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO issue (user_id, project_id, status_id, itype_id) values ('" + UserId + "','" + Pro_id + "','" + Sta_id + "','" + Ity_id + "')", con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        return "error";
    }
    return "success";
}
```

Then your jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnGOlustur_Click').click(function (e) {
        var Pro_id = $('#drop_p').val(); //drop_p is combobox' name.
        var Ity_id = $('#drop_i').val();
        var Sta_id = $('#drop_s').val();


        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: 'GorevEkle.aspx/MyMethod',
            data: "{'project_id':'" + Pro_id + "','status_id':'" + Sta_id + "','itype_id':'" + Ity_id + "'}",
            async: false,
            success: function (response) {
                if(response=="success"){
                $('#drop_p').val(''); $('#drop_i').val(''); $('#drop_s').val('');
                alert("Record saved successfully in database");
                }
                else{
                 //handle error
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("some problem in saving data");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: when I use static here,i have error from combobox and Session.

Comment: @user3627624, Please find the updated answer. Also you need to use `<asp:ScriptManager EnablePageMethods=true />`. Read this http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Comment: I have still some error this three line                            int Pro_id = HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["project_id"];
int Sta_id = Convert.ToInt32(drop_s.SelectedValue);
 int Ity_id = Convert.ToInt32(drop_i.SelectedValue);               it didn't see  combobox.

Comment: @user3627624, You cannot see the combo box since it is not sending the viewstate, and not following the entire page life cycle. If you are not sure, please read more about using jQuery and aspx page method. Also some basic c# programming stuff to convert string to int, etc

Comment: my error is this,"an object reference is required for the nonstatic field method or property.It is working in combobox but in static doesn't.why?